# Trying to embed existDB in my Java Project

Tags: exist-db

I am following the [Depoloyment Guide](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/deployment#embedding) and get stuck at Step 6. I cant find any of the .jar files or even directories listed. My installation is 6.2.0. Am I missing something?

I expected to find the .jar files, listed in the fuide, in my installation folder. I thought the guide might be outdated and used the 2020 release but it was the same.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Deployment Guide is only valid for eXist-db 4.x.x and older. For newer deployments where you want to embed, I would suggest using Maven to add the dependencies that you need. For example, add this to the dependencies of your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.exist-db</groupId>
  <artifactId>exist-core</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```